# Permission denied error when installing gcloud components

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I following the Google Pub/Sub quickstart [guide](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-cli#pubsub-publish-message-java). When I try to run `gcloud components install beta` I get the error below.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.components.install) Permission denied: 
[/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk.staging]

Ensure you have the permissions to access the file and that the file is not in use.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to sudo the command? You might not have permission to write to that folder. `sudo gcloud components install beta`

Comment: That solves it. I feel so stupid.

Comment: No worries, happy you got it working!

Comment: I had the same problem when running `glcoud components update`.  Not sure why I didn't encounter this issue when I originally ran `gcloud components install`.  But @MatthiasBaetens solution worked for me.  Please submit it as an answer Matthias.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @MichaelOsofsky - the answer is there now!

Comment: Goes without saying, anyways FWIW on Windows run gcloud (or the invoking interpreter, cmd/powershell/git-bash/..) as administrator when installing/updating a component

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried to sudo the command? You might not have permission to write to that folder. `sudo gcloud components install beta`.